# composer issue with Merchant SDK for Express Checkout API on Paypal

Tags: php, composer-php, paypal

I want to integrate a method from which a guest also can do payments on my site. So, i am implementing this SDK of paypal. It is required to install the compser and run it for dependencies. So, i ran this command to install composer.phar file inside samples folder

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/var/www/html/app/paypaltest/samples
```

then to install composer i ran this command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

But it is showing error as

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package paypal/merchant-sdk-php 1.0.0 could not be found.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Not sure why i am getting error of version 1.0.0 when i explicitly defining the version number i.e `v3.8.107`
This is the `composer.json` file which i am using. Can anyone help me know what is the issue and why can't i install the composer correctly. Am i missing any thing?

```
{
"name": "paypal/merchant-sdk-php",
"description": "PayPal Merchant SDK for PHP",
"keywords": ["paypal", "php", "sdk"],
"homepage": "https://developer.paypal.com",
"license": "Apache2",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "PayPal",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/contributors"
    }
],
"require": {
    "paypal/merchant-sdk-php":"v3.8.107"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "PayPal\\Service": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\CoreComponentTypes": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\EBLBaseComponents": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\EnhancedDataTypes": "lib/",
        "PayPal\\PayPalAPI": "lib/"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just the following in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "paypal/merchant-sdk-php": "v3.8.107"
    }
}
```